# Best way to implement a nested viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager that inflates a layout that (sometimes) has another viewpager to view photos

```
            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

They both use swipes. I know there is a similar question to this, but seeing as all the answers are old and didn't work for me, does anyone know any good methods of letting users swipe the nested viewpager without forcing a swipe on the parent viewpager? I know it can be done since apps like Diaro do it, but I'm not sure how to go about it myself

Comment: what about merging those parent and child data sets and having a single viewpager?

Comment: @Darish I don't know how to do that can you link me something about it?

Comment: sure, but to be clear, could you please post screenshots or gifs of the desired effect?